# Sum column only of rows that match a condition (of another column)

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a spreadsheet in Google with the following data:

```
**Status         Amount**
Under Review    $120.00
Delivered       $50.00
Paid            $320.00
Paid            $110.00
Under Review    $200.00
```

I want to sum all the column **Amount**, only but of only of those rows that has a **Status** on *'Delivered' or 'Paid'*

With my example, the `SUM` should return $480.00.

I was trying with this formula, but it isn't working

```
=SUMIF(Column Amount,Status={"Delivered","Paid"},Column Amount)
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use the following formula:

```
=SUM(QUERY(A2:B,"select sum(B) where A='Paid' or A='Delivered' group by A"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One of your columns is incorrect, and you need to use the `arrayformula` function. [Documentation here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF([status_column],{"Delivered","Paid"},[amount_column])))`